# How do I retrieve relevance value for ThinkingSphinx search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Is there any way to retrieve relevance values with results with the array returned by ThinkingSphinx? 
Percentages, points or whatever, just something I can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - you can iterate over the result set, and retrieve the weight for each:

```
results = ThinkingSphinx::Search.search(params[:q])
results.each_with_weighting do |result, weight|
  puts "#{result.name} #{weight}"
end
```